# How to avoid duplicate string in a jquery table

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

How to avoid duplicate string in a jquery table sample output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WtdS.jpg) I am looking to consolidate the questions in a one column. The expected table(ouput) look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRa3P.jpg)

```
var list=[
{q:'Question1',r:'response1',credit:4},
{q:'Question2',r:'response2',credit:9},
{q:'Question2',r:'response3',credit:3},
{q:'Question3',r:'response4',credit:8},
{q:'Question3',r:'response5',credit:9},
{q:'Question3',r:'response6',credit:3},
{q:'Question4',r:'response7',credit:7},
{q:'Question4',r:'response8',credit:9},
{q:'Question4',r:'response9',credit:3},
{q:'Question4',r:'response10',credit:1},
{q:'Question5',r:'response11',credit:5},
{q:'Question5',r:'response12',credit:3}
];
 

$.each(result, function (key,qstn) {
                        html += '<tr>';  
                        html += '<td>' + qstn.q+ '</td>'; 
                        html += '<td>' + qstn.response+ '</td>';
                        html += '</tr>';  
                        });
                });
                    $('.tbody').append(html);
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the data you have used for creating table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var list=[
{q:'Question1',r:'Response1',c:4},
{q:'Question2',r:'Response2',c:9},
{q:'Question2',r:'Response3',c:3},
{q:'Question3',r:'Response4',c:8},
{q:'Question3',r:'Response5',c:9},
{q:'Question3',r:'Response6',c:3},
{q:'Question4',r:'Response7',c:7},
{q:'Question4',r:'Response8',c:9},
{q:'Question4',r:'Response9',c:3},
{q:'Question4',r:'Response10',c:1},
{q:'Question5',r:'Response11',c:5},
{q:'Question5',r:'Response12',c:3}
];

var dupes = {};
var singles = [];
$.each(list, function(i, el) {
    if (!dupes[el.q]) {
        dupes[el.q] = true;
        singles.push(el);
    }
});

var html='';
$.each(singles,function(i,el){
var itemArr = $.grep(list, function (item, index) {
       return (item.q==el.q);
   });
   console.log(itemArr);
   
  
  $.each(itemArr,function(iitem,iindex){
  if(iitem==0){
  html += '<tr>';  
  html += '<td rowspan='+itemArr.length+'>' + iindex.q+ '</td><td>'+iindex.r+'</td><td>'+iindex.c+'</td>'; 
  
  html +='</tr>';
  }else{
  html += '<tr><td>' + iindex.r+ '</td><td>' + iindex.c+ '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  }
  });
   
})

 $('.tbody').append(html);  
});
```

HTML

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th>Question<th>Response<th>Count</th>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody" >
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to be a staunch supporter of jQuery - after all, it gave us the power to write short and meaningful code for a variety of different browsers with limited JavaScript capabilities. However, the world has moved on and our "modern" browsers now support many of the features that could for a long time only be found in jQuery.

So, here is my take on an answer without jQuery:

```js
var list=[
{q:'Question1',r:'Response1',c:4},
{q:'Question2',r:'Response2',c:9},{q:'Question2',r:'Response3',c:3},
{q:'Question3',r:'Response4',c:8},{q:'Question3',r:'Response5',c:9},{q:'Question3',r:'Response6',c:3},
{q:'Question4',r:'Response7',c:7},{q:'Question4',r:'Response8',c:9},{q:'Question4',r:'Response9',c:3},{q:'Question4',r:'Response10',c:1},
{q:'Question5',r:'Response11',c:5},{q:'Question5',r:'Response12',c:3}
];
list.cnts=list.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.q]=(a[c.q]||0)+1,a),{}) // calculate rowcounts first

document.querySelector(".tbody").innerHTML=list.map(e=>
  ( e.q!==list.prev && (list.prev=e.q) // not the same question as before?
           ?'<td'+(list.cnts[e.q]>1?' rowspan="'+list.cnts[e.q]+'"':'')+'>'+e.q+'</td>'
           :'' 
  ) + '<td>'+e.r+'</td><td>'+e.c+'</td>'
 ).join('</tr>\n<tr>');
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
<th>Question<th>Response<th>Count</th>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody" >
</tbody>
</table>
```

I feel the line

```
 e.q!==list.prev && (list.prev=e.q)
```

deserves some further explanation. Remember that JavaScript evaluates boolean expressions from left to right in a "lazy" manner. This means it will stop evaluating an `&&`-expression if the first term is evaluated as `false`. So after testing whether `e.q!==list.prev` i. e. if the current question is different from a possibly stored "prev"ious one, it depends on the actual result, whether the second part `(list.prev=e.q)` will be executed. There are two possible cases:

- `e.q!==list.prev` is `true`: this means the current quesion is a "new" one. Now the second expression will be executed, i. e. the property `list.prev` will receive the value of the current question `e.q` and the overall result of the combined expression is `true` (as the question value `e.q`, as long as it is more than an empty string, is evaluated as "truthy").
- `e.q!==list.prev` is `false`: the current question is exactly the same as the (stored) previous one. The second expression will not be executed anymore and the combined expression will return the value `false`

This combined-expression-value now determines whether to insert a `<td>` element for the first column at all. And in case it has more than one answers it will also contain a `'rowspan="'+list.cnts[e.q]+'"'` attribute, making it span several rows.